# PHP Decode gzinflate(base64_decode

Tags: php, hash, base64, decode, encode

I am new here..

I want to ask , i have a code given from my friends now i must break it for the challenge in my school. But i cant decode it because i don't know what is this `hash /` security anything.

Here for the code ..

```
function feoG($aUbehj) { 
    $aUbehj=gzinflate(base64_decode($aUbehj));
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($aUbehj);$i++){
       $aUbehj[$i] = chr(ord($aUbehj[$i])-1);
    }
  return $aUbehj;
}

eval(feoG(""));
```

in the `".."` there is a kind of `base64` code, but when I was clicking `decode hashes` do not match.

**If anyone could help me?**

Thank you

Comment: Maybe your teacher can help.

Comment: It just a challenge with my friend bro , not with the teacher :D